# Save the selected radio button value and text field value into a file

Tags: java

May I know how to save the selected radio button value and text field value into a file by GUI Form?

The form looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boj52.jpg)

My code:

```
 private void SaveButActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try{
    File f=new File("Customer detail.txt");
    String id = this.CusIDTxt.getText();
    String name=NameTxt.getText();
    String ic=ICNoTxt.getText();
    String ph=PhNoTxt.getText();
    String email=EmailAddTxt.getText();
    PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f,true)));
    writer.println(id);
    writer.println(name);
    writer.println(ic);
    writer.println(ph);
    writer.println(email);
    writer.close();
    JOptionPane1.showMessageDialog(this, "Register customer was successful");
    m.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        JOptionPane1.showMessageDialog(this,"All fields must be completed in order to register");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exception ?

Comment: no, when i click save button it goes succefully

Comment: so the only thing you did not get is the text from radio button ?

Comment: Yes, only the text from radio button is not save into the file

Answer (score 0):

So I think something like this https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/jradiobutton/get-selected-jradiobutton-from-buttongroup/ is what you want

Answer (score 0):

You called a file writer but you didn't call a method to write it. For instance, you can try writer.write(name) . It will write the input into the file. You can see into this API's document https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html